# Run a program remotely using SSH, but show output on connected monitor

Tags: server, 16.04, monitor, monitoring

I have a server with a monitor. No GUI installed. When I remotely connect using SSH, I want to launch a program (e.g. glances, htop), but I want it to show its output on the monitor that's connected to the server, not in the SSH session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is using [Byobu](http://byobu.co/). It is an optimal combination of `screen` and `tmux`, with the added advantage of being **actually usable** without learning esoteric keyboard combinations.

On the server, do the following:

- log in with the same user you will use via SSH
- run `byobu`

Via SSH, do the following:

- log in
- run `byobu`

  You are now in the same Byobu session because there is only one per user. Everything you do will get shown also on the monitor connected to the server.
- launch `htop`
- detach the Byobu session by pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>
- log out from the SSH connection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: I would prefer a solution where a user physically at the server won't be able to just press `Ctrl+C` and do whatever, but it's good enough.

Comment: @J2ghz if you don't need user intervention on the server, a nice rule of thumb could be removing the keyboard from it. :)